# my DetailViewController has text field. It appears empty at my first tap after that 

Tags: objective-c

I have a table view which has full of items getting from my database. I open my app. I tap one of my items in table view, then DetailViewController that has only text field does not display anything it is empty. But when I go back to table view then tap any other item again , at this time it displays value what I wanted to display.. It does it for my only first tap.. I have no errors and warnings..  What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you implemented tableView:did**De**selectRowAtIndexPath: instead of tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:.